# MYSQL - FK ERROR

Tags: sql, mysql

Oi, poderiam me ajudar? estou tentando adicionar as FK na tabela funcionarios, só que está dando este erro OBS estou criando as outras tabelas antes da funcionarios

```
20:29:15    CREATE TABLE Funcionarios( id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nomeCompleto VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, rg VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, pis VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, numeroDaCarteira VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, dataNascimento DATE NOT NULL, dataEntrada DATE NOT NULL, dataSaida DATE NULL, endereco VARCHAR(80), bairro VARCHAR(50), cidade VARCHAR(50), estado CHAR(2), telefone VARCHAR(15), salario VARCHAR(10), agencia VARCHAR(10), conta VARCHAR(10), idCargo INT(5), idSetor INT(5), codBanco INT(5), idEstadocivil INT(5),   PRIMARY KEY (id),  FOREIGN KEY (idCargo) REFERENCES Cargo(id), FOREIGN KEY (idSetor) REFERENCES Setor (id), FOREIGN KEY (codBanco) REFERENCES Banco (codigo), FOREIGN KEY (idEstadocivil) REFERENCES EstadoCivil (id)  )  Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.735 sec
```

Não sei o que fazer, estou tendo arrumar e nada, poderiam me ajudar?

```
CREATE DATABASE Empresa2;

CREATE TABLE Funcionarios(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomeCompleto VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
rg VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pis VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
numeroDaCarteira VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
dataNascimento DATE NOT NULL,
dataEntrada DATE NOT NULL,
dataSaida DATE NULL,
endereco VARCHAR(80),
bairro VARCHAR(50),
cidade VARCHAR(50),
estado CHAR(2),
telefone VARCHAR(15),
salario VARCHAR(10),
agencia VARCHAR(10),
conta VARCHAR(10),
idCargo INT(5),
idSetor INT(5),
codBanco INT(5),
idEstadocivil INT(5),


PRIMARY KEY (id),

FOREIGN KEY (idCargo) REFERENCES Cargo(id),
FOREIGN KEY (idSetor) REFERENCES Setor (id),
FOREIGN KEY (codBanco) REFERENCES Banco (codigo),
FOREIGN KEY (idEstadocivil) REFERENCES EstadoCivil (id)

);

CREATE TABLE EstadoCivil(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
referencia VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Cargo(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
referencia VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Setor(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
referencia VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Banco(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
referencia VARCHAR(50),
codigo int(5),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Você está criando a tabela `Funcionarios2` após as outras? E defina os campos estrangeiros como `UNSIGNED`: `idSetor INT(5) UNSIGNED`

Comment: Não, eu criei as outras antes, e depois a funcionarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não estou usando MySql Server, mas dando uma adaptada no seu SQL descobri duas coisas:

1. Você está tentando criar as chaves estrangeiras antes das tabelas,
   isso é impossível.
2. O campo chave estrangeira `codBanco` da tabela de funcionários
   referencia o campo `codigo` da tabela banco, que além de permitir
   nulos não é chave primária (deve referenciar o Id da tabela).

Corrigi esses erros e funcionou normal aqui.

Agora, uma coisa que sempre recomendo fazer é separar os scripts por tarefa, senão vai virar uma maçaroca e você nunca vai entender.

Dessa forma, recomendo que crie os scripts separadamente, sendo um que:

1. Crie o banco e o selecione - i.e `1-CriaESelecionaBanco.sql`.
2. Crie APENAS as tabelas - `2-CriaTabelas.sql`.
3. Depois crie as chaves primárias das tabelas - `3-CriaChavesPrimarias.sql` .
4. Por último APENAS as chaves estrangeiras - `4-CriaChavesEstrangeiras.sql`.

Fazendo isso fica bem mais difícil de errar.